# Setting up an internal pastebin server

Tags: package-management, pastebin

I'd like to set up an internal [pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com) server. Are there any ubuntu packages / docs for setting up pastebin as a server on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Php-pastebin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-pastebin/)

**Description**

pastebin is here to help you collaborate on debugging code snippets. If you're not familiar with the idea, most people use it like this: submit a code fragment to pastebin, getting a url like hxxp://yoursite.com/1234, paste the url into an IRC or IM conversation, someone responds by reading and perhaps submitting a modification of your code, you then view the modification, maybe using the built in diff tool to help locate the changes

**Features**

```
Auto delete pastes
Auto sitemap
54 languages ​​recognized
Management theme
Hit pastes
```

[Php-pastebin Web Site](http://php-pastebin.com/)